# Live Streaming options

Tags: video-streaming, live

I would like to know why people are using streaming technologies such as Flash media server and other services when they can use skype or tokbox(if want to customise) for broadcasting their video with audio.

Is there any thing that is stopping people from using free services?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stream to thousands of viewers with services like Skype, they're intended for one to one (or some) communication.